# JPA/EclipseLink annotation for complex Map like : Map<String, List<String>>()

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

Is it possible to annotate a structure like :

- Map < String, List < String > >(); ?

via JPA or/and EclipseLink ?

If yeas, what's the SQL SCHEME (as tables) is generated applying it ?

Thanks, 
Simeon

Answer (score 4):

No this is not directly supported by JPA.

The best thing to do is to create an object/Entity that defines/maps to the relationship, which is normally a better model in general than a complex data structure.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices